# How can I avoid deleting a ul element with this code?

Tags: jquery

I have an infinite scrolling gallery that uses markup like this (transformed through CSS to appear horizontal):

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><img id="placeHolder" class="photo" .../></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now, I have some jQuery that populates the UL element with bullets (li) which themselves contain images.

Past a certain defined number of images the first image should be removed.
This is what the following code is supposed to do.

```
// Limit to max
if( $('.photo:visible').size() >= maxPhotos ){
        $(".photo:first").parent().remove(); // Remove li also removes img
}
```

However, it appears that it also removes the UL after a certain time.

Any suggestions on how I could avoid this?

Comment: may be is the time to read the DOM for jquery ? What's happen if you adding a var toto = $(".photo:first").parent().remove(); after the first image adding ?

Comment: Are you sure it is removing the `ul`? Check the page source, if the `ul` is empty and it is not styled at all I don't think it will show up.

Comment: what happens if you add `if ($(".photo:first").parent().attr("tagName") == "li")` before removing?

Comment: Evidently `$(".photo:first").parent()` is matching a `<ul>`. Can't see that happening given the information you've provided, though.

Comment: @Matt Ball @Jack: Inspecting the element in Chrome shows the ul has disappeared: `<div id="slideshow"><!-- Photos go here --></div>`. As far as I can see the only code that removes anything is what I've posted above. @pinouchon: I'll give that a try.

Comment: @Matt Ball Tell my if i am wrong, but i think it is matching li, not ul : http://jsfiddle.net/uEwk6/

Comment: @pinouchon: It is doing it's job properly to begin with. The photos are added on edge detection and it's only after 15 minutes or more that I've noticed the div is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var $photos = $('.photo:visible');
if( $photos.length >= maxPhotos ){
    $photos.first().parent('li').remove();
}
```

- [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent) can take a selector
- Don't select the `.photo` elements twice
- Use `.length` instead of `.size()`

Comment: This did the trick. I'll figure out what was happening exactly. If you have an FB profile you can check the work-in-progress here: http://apps.facebook.com/kisslook/

Answer (score 1):

You could just check to make sure it's an `<li>` tag before removing.

```
// Limit to max
if( $('.photo:visible').size() >= maxPhotos && $(".photo:first").parent().tagName == 'li'){
        $(".photo:first").parent().remove(); // Remove li also removes img
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Straightforward solution but didn't know the proper syntax.

Comment: -1. This is a terribly non-idiomatic way to check the parent. Just [pass a selector to `.parent()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914661/how-can-i-avoid-deleting-a-ul-element-with-this-code/6915040#6915040).

Comment: Yeah Matt is right, you should follow his solution.  I keep forgetting about the parent selectors.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if( $('.photo:visible').size() >= maxPhotos ){
        $(".photo:first").closest("li").remove(); // Remove li also removes img
}
```

Comment: This could potentially be really far up the DOM tree though.

Comment: It shuold acutally find the li which is the parent of img element.

Comment: No not necessarily a parent. It will find an ancestor.

Comment: Closest makes sure it will find the immediate element matching the selector passed. Take a look at this [link](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: "Get the first ancestor element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree."

Comment: Yes, it will return the li element. Read the statement carefully..beginning from the current element..it finds the first ancestor(parent is also called as ancestor element). So in this case li will be selected.

Comment: To make it even more clear take a look at this fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/2k2Yg/). Hope this will make your fundamentals clear.

Comment: Yeah, but it will also remove something like this...

ul > li > div > ul > img

he possibly has an invalid dom tree if it's removing the parent and removing the ul

Answer (score 1):

This would ensure that it was an li tag

```
if( $('.photo:visible').size() >= maxPhotos ){
    $(".photo:first").closest('li').remove(); // Remove li also removes img
}
```